# EditText скрывает все элементы

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditText расположен внизу активности и при получении фокуса скрывает все элементы расположенные выше (ListView и тулбар), как быть?

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:background="@color/background_toolbar"
    android:layout_weight="0">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```